# In Delphi TClientDataSet not populating ProviderName

Tags: delphi, isapi

I created a ISAPI DLL server using DataSnap webbroker wizard on REST.  I then installed it on IIS and tested sucessfully by creating a client and connecting to DSRestConnection1.

I put a TDatasetProver on server and a TClientDataSet on client. Then for TClientDataSet property ProiverName is not getting populated.

Also I dropped a TSQLConnection on client and set its Driver property to Datasnap. I set host property to LocalHost. But when I try to set property Connected=True , it throw error "Socket Error #10061 Connection Refused.."

Please let me know if you have any idea why my clientDataset is not seeing Providers on server and also why SQLConnection is not getting connected.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a [TDSProviderConnection](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Datasnap.DSConnect.TDSProviderConnection) between the TSQLConnection and the TClientDataSet.

Comment: Thanks Uwe for reply. Sorry I did put TDSProviderConnection and still no luck. But even if we ignore this issue for a moment, why am I not able to set SQLConnection connected property to true. I keep getting "Socket Error #10061 Connection Refused..". I am having so much hard time finding a single ISAPI database tutorial using REST.  It will be really helpful if you can put a YouTube tutorial on this. Regards.

Comment: Actually I didn't test ist, but to my knowledge the DataSetProvider approach is not working with REST. For REST you have to use a TDSRESTConnection instead of a TSQLConnection. To transfer a dataset via REST implement a method in the server class returning the dataset. You can find some information here: http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/delphi_xe5_update2_datasnap_firedac.html

Comment: Thanks Uwe for your answer. I did used  TDSRESTConnection but I was not getting any luck. Finally found out that problem was with port# 80. Initially my port # was empty.